# What did David did sing or play for Saul?

Tags: music, king-david, king-saul

What song or melody did David play for Saul?
The song seems to controle the demon,but what did he sing or play?

Does the Torah or the sages tell us?

Comment: Note that "demon" seems to have been mental illness.

Comment: Perhaps he sang Tehillim?

Comment: @DanF  I also think Tehillim,but what psalm?

Comment: The verse stating Sauls' request in I Samuel 16:16 - 17 state that Saul wanted someone who knows how to play the harp. It is possible that what David played may not have been related to any particular song per se. Playing the harp certainly does not imply any verbal song, singing or anything having words.

Comment: There is no answer to this question?

Comment: I have to give someone  the bounty.If someone would try to give a good answer will get the Bounty.